# Can we make such a class which is not inherits Object class

Tags: java

Can we make such a class which is not inherits Object class directly or indirectly in java.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Every single class inherits from `Object` class, it's the way Java is designed.

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).